# How to filter the array of object by matching all values instead of one

Tags: javascript, filter, ecmascript-2016

I am implementing a filter. it works fine. the problem is it's just matching a single object value instead of all value matching.

**Matching means here is, let it be contain any single letter in the value**

example: here is my object

`{name:"D",color:"Green",size:50}`

in case if i pass the filter object as :

`let filter1 = {color:"Blu",size:'50'};`

at present I am getting single result by matching size. But the color is not matching at all. so the result should be empty.

How to mach all values in the object and get the filtered value.

[Live Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/mskrnaL4/)

Code :

```
const nestedFilter = (targetArray, filters) => targetArray.filter(o => Object.keys(filters).find(k => filters[k].includes(o[k])));

let products = [
  {name:"A",color:"Blue",size:70},
  {name:"B",color:"Blue",size:60},
  {name:"C",color:"Black",size:70},
  {name:"D",color:"Green",size:50}
];

let filter1 = {color:"Blu",size:'50'};


console.log(nestedFilter(products, filter1));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace the `.find` invocation with `.every`. Be aware though that by using `includes` you expect your property values to be String.

If you want `includes` to work to other way round, so that the filter value can be a substring of the data, you should do:

```
const nestedFilter = (targetArray, filters) => 
    targetArray.filter(o => Object.keys(filters).every(k =>
        String(o[k]).includes(filters[k]))
    )
)
```

The `o[k]` value needs to be converted to string, as otherwise you cannot apply `includes` to it (cf. `size` which is a number)

Comment: I did, after I pass this value getting empty instead of 1. `let filter1 = {color:"Gr",size:'50'};`

Comment: If you want the `includes` to work, you should swap the direction of it. See addition to my answer. Note how `includes` is applies to the "longer" string: `o[k]`

Comment: I am not looking for `===`, for me if partially contains also ok. `Gr` is partial here.

Comment: I see, see what I wrote and added.

Answer (score 0):

Check whether `every` of the `Object.entries` of the filter passed is equal to the same entry on the object being iterated over. If you want partial matches and are using different types of variables, it sounds like you also need to coerce them to strings first, so you can use `.includes`.

```js
const nestedFilter = (targetArray, filters) => targetArray.filter(
  obj => Object.entries(filters).every(
    ([key, val]) => String(obj[key]).includes(val)
  )
);

let products = [
  {name:"A",color:"Blue",size:70},
  {name:"B",color:"Blue",size:60},
  {name:"C",color:"Black",size:70},
  {name:"D",color:"Green",size:50},
  {name:"E",color:"Blu",size:'50'}
];

let filter1 = {color:"Blu",size:'70'};


console.log(nestedFilter(products, filter1));
```

Comment: If I pass `let filter1 = {color:"Blu",size:'70'};` getting nothing. value can be partially contain fine for me. example for above i expected result as `{name:"A",color:"Blue",size:70},`

Comment: Sounds like you need to coerce the non-strings to strings too, if you want `.includes` to work with a partial match